# Is there a rule change in more recent versions of Bohnanza?

Tags: bohnanza

The first time I played Bohnanza and according to the Wikipedia summary, there is a rule that allows purchasing a third field.

However, I can't find any reference to this in the rules of the game I have, which is version 5.0 (2016).

Is it the case that this rule was ommited, and what is the reasoning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the rules were updated sometime around 2011.

There is a discussion about the rules change at boardgamegeek [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1869340/third-bean-field-purchase-option-removed-recent-ri).

It seems it was done because purchasing a third field was almost always a mistake; so he option added no real strategic value.